# State Management in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-context, react-state-management

Which technique is better for state management in react app?
Actually I want to create a big app where I've to manage my state which technique is optimal for state management context, Redux or react custom hook?

Comment: Here is a list of [React State Management Libraries](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/awesome-react-state-management). As so far redux is the most popular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am personally more inclined towards Redux. But if you are a beginner trying to learn Redux you might have some hard time until you understand it. Once you get it you will also like it. Rather than building your own custom hook, It's better to use Redux as if anything goes wrong/you are struck with something, you have community to support and You can also dispatch async calls using some middleware libs like redux-thunk, etc. You can use Redux with forms as well. I guess if you end building your custom hooks you might end up wasting time, taking care of all these.

Comment: Ok about a custom hook but why I don't use the context mechanism?

Comment: For your question the official Context Doc says.                                          
      Context is primarily used when some data needs to be accessible by many components at different nesting levels. Apply it sparingly because it makes component reuse more difficult.

Comment: Hope you get it (Apply it sparingly because it makes component reuse more difficult.) This is the point I am stressing about.

Comment: I guess you are interested in using Hooks and Context. Hope this might help you. 
 https://medium.com/yld-engineering-blog/rolling-your-own-redux-with-react-hooks-and-context-bbeea18b1253

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it is better to go ahead with Redux, because it is easier to handle large applications with Redux. It has only a single store, which is basically a javascript object. You can divide the store into many pieces, each piece will be for a particular part of the application. All these pieces will be joined together using the combineReducers function provided by redux.

Answer (score 1):

React is a state management library and with the release of React hooks and massive improvements to React context this method of state management has been drastically simplified.

I think in 99% of the situations we do not need redux and add one layer of complexity to project. 
For big scale app maybe redux is better choice. but if you choose React for state management you need good information about some concepts and this concepts is:

1. Local state vs global state(some component needs local state and putting all of their state in global state leads to a lot of problems)
2. react context and [prop drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling) problem and How to use React Context effectively
3. react hooks especially useReducer and useContext
4. immutable state

Answer (score 1):

You would always need to ask yourself the question: Do i need an additional library?

Redux is on its decline in popularity, due to improvements on Reacts native state management. There is a reason for that!

If you want to work for a company thats not brand new, there is a chance you have to use redux. I was fortunate enough to convince my team to use our own state management library build only with React.useState under the hood.

If your application state logic is quite simple, meaning: states are mostly local, shared state are mostly between parent-child relationship and different states are not heavily depending on each other, then I recommend only using React useState and useReducer (in case you like to use reducers).

Once your application state is getting complicated, you need to have some sort extra stuff of global state management.

The most important thing you need to know about React.useState is, that the returned setState function is your connection to that components state. Lets assume we can take that function out of the component and use it somewhere else. This way you have a function to update your state from outside of your component.

```
export let exportedStateSetter;

const Component = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    exportedStateSetter = setState;
    return () => exportedStateSetter = undefined;
  });

  return <div>{state}</div>
};
```

In the example above, you can now import the exportedStateSetter and use it somewhere else to update the state of this Component.

!This is not a best pracitce example, this is a simple visualization.

When you think very critically about this, you will realize that now you know how to set a components state from outside of a component, you know how to set states globally.

I stringly recommend using this approach to either build your own global state library or use some that i have created based on what i explained:

```
npm install --save react-global-state-hook  // simple
npm install --save rx-global                // complex
```

To wrap it up: Dont use Redux, if not required by a job. You can always use Redux conventions, by seperating state into stores, update state with a reducer and actions that interact with the state. For that you can use native React state management, if not only React.useState when used properly. React provides you with everything you need and everything you need to build yourself.

I had the best developer experiences with my own libraries that evolved over time. It forces you to understand state management in general and the framework you are using.

Im open for any feedback on the 2 libraries and if you have any questions regarding state, please feel free to keep posting.